# Packages being added to Source Control

Tags: visual-studio-2013, version-control, nuget

I have created a `nuget.config` file and placed it in the solution root for my project(s).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <config>
        <add key="repositorypath" value="..\packages" />
        <solution>
            <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
        </solution>
    </config>
</configuration>
```

When I build the project with VS2015, everything runs fine. It downloads the nuget packages, but does not attempt to add them to source control. However, when I try to run the same project build in VS2013, with a clean build (i.e. no packages), it will download them successfully, but always adds them to source.

VS1013 has the Nuget v2.8.60723.765 extension installed - and no updates are listed as available from extension manager. I had read that there [was a problem](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/980) with this feature, but that appears to be in v3 (and has been fixed in 3.2).

I have attempted to place the config file both in the solution root (which apparently should work) *and* in a .nuget folder off the solution root. Neither solution solved the issue.

Am I missing something in the config file that would allow VS2013 to *not* add these package folders to source control?